# Android Studio not recognizing package path

Tags: java, android, xml

[See Image Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ejQD.png) I am trying to make a reference to the path of the java class inside the activity package but its not being picked up

Comment: It needs to be a fully-qualified class name.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.